# putting symbol on every repeatation of the first column value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, awk

Hii experts i have a input file that looks like as below, where the first column values are repeated after some time,Now i want to separate the repeated blocks with symbol >.

```
 0.0     0.0   0.50000E+00
 5.0     0.0   0.80000E+00
10.0     0.0   0.80000E+00
 0.0     1.0   0.10000E+00
 5.0     1.0   0.90000E+00
10.0     1.0   0.30000E+00
 0.0     2.0   0.90000E+00
 5.0     2.0   0.50000E+00
10.0     2.0   0.60000E+00
```

Now i want to put > symbol on every repetation of the first column value so that my output should be something like

```
  >       >      >
 0.0     0.0   0.50000E+00
 5.0     0.0   0.80000E+00
10.0     0.0   0.80000E+00
  >       >      >
 0.0     1.0   0.10000E+00
 5.0     1.0   0.90000E+00
10.0     1.0   0.30000E+00
  >       >      >
 0.0     2.0   0.90000E+00
 5.0     2.0   0.50000E+00
10.0     2.0   0.60000E+00
```

i tried the below script: but its only reading the file

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in `cat file.txt`
do
sed '>' $file
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checks whether first field is lower than the previous record

```
$ awk '!(p<$1){k=$0; gsub(/\S+/,">",k); print k} {p=$1}1' file | column -t
>     >    >
0.0   0.0  0.50000E+00
5.0   0.0  0.80000E+00
10.0  0.0  0.80000E+00
>     >    >
0.0   1.0  0.10000E+00
5.0   1.0  0.90000E+00
10.0  1.0  0.30000E+00
>     >    >
0.0   2.0  0.90000E+00
5.0   2.0  0.50000E+00
10.0  2.0  0.60000E+00
```

if you already know the block size (here 3), with `sed`

```
$ sed '1~3i> > >' file | column -t
>     >    >
0.0   0.0  0.50000E+00
5.0   0.0  0.80000E+00
10.0  0.0  0.80000E+00
>     >    >
0.0   1.0  0.10000E+00
5.0   1.0  0.90000E+00
10.0  1.0  0.30000E+00
>     >    >
0.0   2.0  0.90000E+00
5.0   2.0  0.50000E+00
10.0  2.0  0.60000E+00
```

if the spacing need to be preserved, slightly different approach is needed.